# Xcode 12: CompileAssetCatalog Unity-iPhone/Images.xcassets fails

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, jenkins

Ever since updating to Xcode 12 our CI machine has been getting weird error when executing command line build with xcodebuild. Same error won't occure in Xcode where the same build gets archived and build correctly. It seems that the cause of the build process error is this:

```
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/eskari_daily_ios/Builds/temp/Unity-iPhone/Images.xcassets: error: Failed to find newest available Simulator runtime
    Underlying Errors:
        Description: No available runtime found from: [
    watchOS 7.0 (7.0 - 18R382) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.watchOS-7-0 (unavailable, failed to open liblaunch_sim.dylib) ==> not available: Error Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=401 "The watchOS 7.0 simulator runtime is not available." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The watchOS 7.0 simulator runtime is not available., NSUnderlyingError=0x7f9d4d038cb0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=53 "Software caused connection abort" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=XPC error talking to SimLaunchHostService: <error: 0x7fff8f3a89a0> { count = 1, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0, contents =
    "XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x7fff8f3a8b08> { length = 18, contents = "Connection invalid" }
```

Which is pretty weird because our project does not target Apple watchOS.

Any clues or ideas how to tackle the issue? This issue does not occure on my computer that runs same Xcode 12 version and has been updated to the latest OSX version.

Command line invocation:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -project Builds/temp/Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj -scheme Unity-iPhone -sdk iphoneos -configuration Release archive -archivePath Builds/temp/archive/app.xcarchive -derivedDataPath Builds/temp/derivedData

Other relevant build log is here:

```
CompileAssetCatalog derivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/daily.app Unity-iPhone/Images.xcassets
    cd /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/eskari_daily_ios/Builds/temp
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/Android/android-ndk-r16b:/usr/local/bin:/Library/Android/android-ndk-r16b:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/actool --output-format human-readable-text --notices --warnings --export-dependency-info /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/eskari_daily_ios/Builds/temp/derivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/assetcatalog_dependencies --output-partial-info-plist /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/eskari_daily_ios/Builds/temp/derivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist --app-icon AppIcon --compress-pngs --enable-on-demand-resources YES --development-region English --target-device iphone --target-device ipad --minimum-deployment-target 10.0 --platform iphoneos --compile /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/eskari_daily_ios/Builds/temp/derivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/daily.app /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/eskari_daily_ios/Builds/temp/Unity-iPhone/Images.xcassets
/* com.apple.actool.errors */
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/eskari_daily_ios/Builds/temp/Unity-iPhone/Images.xcassets: error: Failed to find newest available Simulator runtime
    Underlying Errors:
        Description: No available runtime found from: [
    watchOS 7.0 (7.0 - 18R382) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.watchOS-7-0 (unavailable, failed to open liblaunch_sim.dylib) ==> not available: Error Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=401 "The watchOS 7.0 simulator runtime is not available." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The watchOS 7.0 simulator runtime is not available., NSUnderlyingError=0x7f9d4d038cb0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=53 "Software caused connection abort" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=XPC error talking to SimLaunchHostService: <error: 0x7fff8f3a89a0> { count = 1, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0, contents =
    "XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x7fff8f3a8b08> { length = 18, contents = "Connection invalid" }
}}}, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Unable to open liblaunch_sim.dylib.  Try reinstalling Xcode or the simulator runtime., NSLocalizedFailureReason=failed to open liblaunch_sim.dylib},
    tvOS 14.0 (14.0 - 18J383) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.tvOS-14-0 (unavailable, failed to open liblaunch_sim.dylib) ==> not available: Error Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=401 "The tvOS 14.0 simulator runtime is not available." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The tvOS 14.0 simulator runtime is not available., NSUnderlyingError=0x7f9d4d004c40 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=53 "Software caused connection abort" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=XPC error talking to SimLaunchHostService: <error: 0x7fff8f3a89a0> { count = 1, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0, contents =
    "XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x7fff8f3a8b08> { length = 18, contents = "Connection invalid" }
}}}, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Unable to open liblaunch_sim.dylib.  Try reinstalling Xcode or the simulator runtime., NSLocalizedFailureReason=failed to open liblaunch_sim.dylib},
    iOS 14.1 (14.1 - 18A8394) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-1 (unavailable, failed to open liblaunch_sim.dylib) ==> not available: Error Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=401 "The iOS 14.1 simulator runtime is not available." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The iOS 14.1 simulator runtime is not available., NSUnderlyingError=0x7f9d4d038cb0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=53 "Software caused connection abort" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=XPC error talking to SimLaunchHostService: <error: 0x7fff8f3a89a0> { count = 1, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0, contents =
    "XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x7fff8f3a8b08> { length = 18, contents = "Connection invalid" }
}}}, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Unable to open liblaunch_sim.dylib.  Try reinstalling Xcode or the simulator runtime., NSLocalizedFailureReason=failed to open liblaunch_sim.dylib},
] when matching for <IBCocoaTouchPlatformToolDescription: 0x7f9d4e14a0f0> System content for IBCocoaTouchFramework-fourteenAndLater <IBScaleFactorDeviceTypeDescription: 0x7f9d4b4e3e30> scaleFactor=2x, renderMode.identifier=(null), idiom=<IBIPhoneIdiom: 0x7f9d4e52bb40> runtime=<IBCocoaTouchTargetRuntime: 0x7f9d4b488d30>
/* com.apple.actool.document.notices */
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/eskari_daily_ios/Builds/temp/Unity-iPhone/Images.xcassets:./AppIcon.appiconset/[][ipad][76x76][][][1x][][]: notice: 76x76@1x app icons only apply to iPad apps targeting releases of iOS prior to 10.0.
/* com.apple.actool.compilation-results */
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/eskari_daily_ios/Builds/temp/derivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/daily.app/AppIcon20x20@2x.png
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/eskari_daily_ios/Builds/temp/derivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/daily.app/AppIcon20x20@2x~ipad.png
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/eskari_daily_ios/Builds/temp/derivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/daily.app/AppIcon20x20@3x.png
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/eskari_daily_ios/Builds/temp/derivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/daily.app/AppIcon20x20~ipad.png
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/eskari_daily_ios/Builds/temp/derivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/daily.app/AppIcon29x29.png
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/eskari_daily_ios/Builds/temp/derivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/daily.app/AppIcon29x29@2x.png
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/eskari_daily_ios/Builds/temp/derivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/daily.app/AppIcon29x29@2x~ipad.png
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/eskari_daily_ios/Builds/temp/derivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/daily.app/AppIcon29x29@3x.png
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/eskari_daily_ios/Builds/temp/derivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/daily.app/AppIcon29x29~ipad.png
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/eskari_daily_ios/Builds/temp/derivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/daily.app/AppIcon40x40@2x.png
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/eskari_daily_ios/Builds/temp/derivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/daily.app/AppIcon40x40@2x~ipad.png
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/eskari_daily_ios/Builds/temp/derivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/daily.app/AppIcon40x40@3x.png
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/eskari_daily_ios/Builds/temp/derivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/daily.app/AppIcon40x40~ipad.png
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/eskari_daily_ios/Builds/temp/derivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/daily.app/AppIcon60x60@2x.png
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/eskari_daily_ios/Builds/temp/derivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/daily.app/AppIcon60x60@3x.png
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/eskari_daily_ios/Builds/temp/derivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/daily.app/AppIcon76x76@2x~ipad.png
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/eskari_daily_ios/Builds/temp/derivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/daily.app/AppIcon76x76~ipad.png
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/eskari_daily_ios/Builds/temp/derivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/daily.app/AppIcon83.5x83.5@2x~ipad.png
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/eskari_daily_ios/Builds/temp/derivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist


** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileAssetCatalog derivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/daily.app Unity-iPhone/Images.xcassets
(1 failure)
```

Answer (score 0):

Final solution for this issue was to reinstall Jenkins. Old Jenkins installer had installed Jenkins in way that is no longer supported by apple.

Basically:

1. Install Jenkins via homebrew
2. copy jobs, workspace, plugins.. to new jenkins
3. setup authentications to new jenkins
4. Use new Jenkins that is setup on your account and the issue is gone.

Reference:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/664731